# Can you look if a link has an embed in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a bot that sorts thro links and only outputs the one which give an embed (aka dont lead to an error page)
Is there any way to make the bot sort thro them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: More information is required, what do you mean by error, does the site raise a 404 or something else? What have you tried? More information will definitely make it easier to answer

Comment: An error means a 404. Bassically if you text the link, a little embed describing the link will appear (again, if it doesnt lead to a 404) i wanna detect that without texting the message

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a link is broken or not by sending a request to the site

```py
import requests

response = requests.get(link) #link as string

if response.status_code//100 == 2:
    print("connection succesful")
else:
    print("connection unsuccesful")
```

We check if the status code starts with a 2. It is a 3 digit integer.

### References:

- [requests.get](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp)
- [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)